# images stretching of my website in safari browserr

Tags: css, image, safari, mobile-safari

My images of [this site](http://supplylife.com.br/produtos.html) are stretching only in the safari.

[image: image of website]

anyone can help me with this?

Comment: No. This is not a jobs board. You don't hire someone to come over to look at your problem. You post your code here. Pictures of problems are essentially useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the min-height property on the image.

```
.ft-gallery-v2 .ft-class-item .image img {
    width: 100%;
    /* min-height: 100%; */
 }
```